# How to receive sms in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am new to android and i am using android 2.1 for some sms_receive thing: when an sms received,it won't work... Nothing happens when sms received and I have force close, help!

**Code for androidmanifest.xml:**

```
<uses-sdk android:minsdkversion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity>
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.smsreceiver.SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Class RSMSActivity:**

```
public class RSMSActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SHORTCODE = "55443";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        // Create messages for each incoming PDU
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            sms[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }
        for (SmsMessage msg : sms) {
            // Verify if the message came from our known sender
            if (TextUtils.equals(msg.getOriginatingAddress(), "09358921973")) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Received message from the mothership: " + msg.getMessageBody(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your class name is wrong, according to your manifest file it should be like

```
 public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your class name from **RSMSActivity**  to **SmsReceiver** .
Check it for more:

- [How-to-receive-sms](http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.com/2012/11/how-to-receive-sms.html)